# Repeating background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put my picture in the background to take the entire screen but image is not repeating.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nee2O.png)

```
<div id="backgrounddiv">
  <img id="background" src="http://i.imgur.com/nhQAcos.jpg">
</div>




#background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    image-repeat: repeat;
}

#backgrounddiv {
    position: absolute; 
    z-index:0; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: Try `background-repeat`

Comment: You can not just invent your own CSS properties and hope that achieves anything ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to be using is [background-repeat](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-repeat)

The css syntax:

`background-repeat: repeat|repeat-x|repeat-y|no-repeat|initial|inherit;`

So it should look like this:

```css
div {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/nhQAcos.jpg);
    background-repeat:initial;
}
```

or if you want it to repeat vertically...

```css
div {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/nhQAcos.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```